# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory shutil

Tags: python, shutil

im haveing a really simple code but for some reason i get Err no 2
here is the code :

```
import os, shutil

src=r"C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/FilesPy"
des=r"C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/tryPy/Output"
srcFile=r"C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/tryPy/Input/FilesToCopy.txt"

srcFile=open(srcFile,'a+')

for line in srcFile:
    name=line.rstrip()
    pathS=os.path.join(src,name)
    pathD=os.path.join(des,name)
    if os.path.exists(pathS):
        shutil.copy(pathS,des)

    else:
        print 'false' + path
```

but all i get is :

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/tryPy/Output\\blatwo.docx'
```

i really don't know what to do tried reasearching the whole net didn't get an answer please help me.

thanks :)

***edit:***
here is the full trace of the run on eclipse:

```
pydev debugger
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\EasyEclipse-for-Python-1.3.1\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_1.3.13\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 803, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "D:\EasyEclipse-for-Python-1.3.1\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_1.3.13\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 655, in run
    execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "D:\Python\CopyChosenFiles\Copy of CopyFiles.py", line 16, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(pathS,pathD)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py", line 128, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'rb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/tryPy/Output\\blatwo.docx'
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_exc'" in <function _remove at 0x00AC52B0> ignored
```

Comment: @Levon there i edited it and added the right code..

Comment: what line?  Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: well, i tried this already thats why i droped the pathD and put des insted = \ still the same error..

Comment: @mgilson i edited my question and adde the full trace

Comment: does `des` directory exist? Is the `name` pure ASCII? the traceback is not real: line 83 should be `with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, good catch; and if the traceback _is_ real, then as bizarre as it seems, that may be the source of the error. Opening a nonexistent file in read mode throws that exact error. DrDark, change line 83 in `shutil.py` to `with open(dst, 'rb') as fdst:`. Take care to preserve indentation.

Comment: @senderle -- that seems really strange to me.  Also strange is that the traceback references `shutil.copy2` whereas DrDark's code references `shutil.copy`

Answer (score 2):

Replace the variable assignments with this:

```
src = os.path.join('C:', 'Documents and Settings', 'user', 'Desktop', 'FilesPy')
des = os.path.join('C:', 'Documents and Settings', 'user', 'Desktop', 'tryPy', 'Output')
srcFile = os.path.join('C:', 'Documents and Settings', 'user', 'Desktop', 'tryPy', 'Input', 'FilesToCopy.txt')
```

Or, use backslashes in the paths, since you're using windows...

```
src = r"C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\FilesPy"
des = r"C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\tryPy\Output"
srcFile = r"C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\tryPy\Input\FilesToCopy.txt"
```